# Why am I getting ClassNotFoundException when I define <shape> in layout XML?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to draw a rectangle by including this in `/layout/myactivity.xml`:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
  <corners
      android:radius="2dp"
      android:topRightRadius="0dp"
      android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
      android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" />
  <stroke
      android:width="1dp"
      android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
```

When I try to run the project I get:

```
05-12 23:37:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(541): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.shape
05-12 23:37:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
05-12 23:37:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
05-12 23:37:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
05-12 23:37:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
05-12 23:37:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:636)
05-12 23:37:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
05-12 23:37:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
05-12 23:37:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
05-12 23:37:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  ... 22 more
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Put your shape file in /res/drawable instead of /res/layout as Sam said.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your XML code is fine, the location is the problem. Instead of having this file in your `res/layout` folder, you will want to save it in `res/drawable` or a specific drawable folder like `res/drawable-xhdpi`.

Comment: @johndodo This is what you need to do

Comment: I have the XML in drawable/roundbutton.xml but still getting this error ¿?